# Clarifying how we can identify $SK_1(R)$ with set of path components

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative Banach algebra.

Let $E_n$ denote the group generated by $n\times n$ elementary matrices. $SK_1(R)$ denotes the kernel of the induced determinant map $K_1(R) \to R^{\times}$.

In the *K-book*, Weibel states,

> $E_n(R)$ is the path component of the identity matrix $I_n$ for any
>   $n\geq 2$. Hence we may identify the $SK_1(R)$ with the set
>   $\pi_0{SL}(R)$.

I do not see how the second statement follows from the first. I am just looking for a brief explanation that helps me make sense of this lemma.

Comment: What is the definition of $K_1(R)$?

Comment: @MikeMiller It is the abelianization of the infinite general linear group over $R$.

Comment: The thing that confused me earlier is that your statement "$E_n(R)$ is the path component of the identity matrix $I_n$" means the path-component inside $SL_n(R)$, as opposed to $GL_n(R)$; in retrospect this should have been clear, given that $E_n(R) \subset SL_n(R)$!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're interested in $K_1(R) = GL_\infty(R)/E_\infty(R)$, where these are defined as the colimits of the corresponding terms $GL_n(R)$ and $E_n(R)$.

What you know is that $E_\infty(R)$ is a normal subgroup of $GL_\infty(R)$ that is contained inside $SL_\infty(R) = \text{ker}(\det)$ (another normal subgroup). Now the third isomorphism theorem gives $$\left(GL_\infty(R)/E_\infty(R)\right)/\left(SL_\infty(R)/E_\infty(R)\right) = GL_\infty(R)/SL_\infty(R);$$ rephrasing, there is a short exact sequence $$SL_\infty(R)/E_\infty(R) \to GL_\infty(R)/E_\infty(R) \to GL_\infty(R)/SL_\infty(R).$$

The second term is $K_1(R)$ and the last term is $R^\times$, both by definition. But now you know from Weibel's proposition 1.5 (the one that you quote) that the first term is $\pi_0 SL_\infty(R)$, because for any topological group $G$, the quotient $G/G_0$ by the identity component is naturally identified with $\pi_0 G$. You also know the second term is $R^\times$. So you have a short exact sequence $$\pi_0 SL_\infty(R) \to K_1(R) \to R^\times,$$ where the last map is the determinant. Of course, the kernel of the determinant map $K_1(R) \to R^\times$ is precisely how $SK_1(R)$ is defined, so we have the desired result.